# Trackpad lenovo ideapad 3 Ubuntu not working

Tags: drivers, touchpad, lenovo, 20.10, ideapad

I tried all I found, but can not make it work. It doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.10 and neither in 20.04. What should I do?

```
$ xinput --list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse                       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]


$ grep -iA2 touchpad /proc/bus/input/devices

N: Name="MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-MSFT0001:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-MSFT0001:00/0018:04F3:3140.0001/input/input12

$ ls $(find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type d -name mouse)

appletouch.ko  cyapatp.ko   gpio_mouse.ko  sermouse.ko       synaptics_usb.ko
bcm5974.ko     elan_i2c.ko  psmouse.ko     synaptics_i2c.ko  vsxxxaa.ko

$ sudo dmesg


[    0.788754] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    0.793899] i2c_hid i2c-MSFT0001:00: supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.793916] i2c_hid i2c-MSFT0001:00: supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.797696] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
```

Also the lights of the keyboard don't turn on and the brightness of the screen doesn't change

It got somehow solved. I had some problems with python, basically damaged the computer, had to reinstall all again and now the trackpad works. Should I mark the post as answered?

Comment: The lights of the keyboard are working now, I updated the kernel and there is a function in the keyboard for that, the touchpad and the brightness of the screen still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this same issue regarding non-working touchpad with new Lenovo Ideapad 3 and V15 laptops. Please try to change grub settings according to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1302468/9578

Comment: I tried temporarily Add a Kernel Boot Parameter for Testing, like is described on this link:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

It didn't work.

Comment: In my testing I had to add BOTH of these parameters: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nocrs"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="initcall_blacklist=elants_i2c_driver_init"

Comment: I did it like that. I actually tried three different things:
1°:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nocrs quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs quiet splash"
`
2°:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nocrs"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="initcall_blacklist=elants_i2c_driver_init"
`
3°:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
`
Just that I substituted, not added, the lines:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
`
I think you meant substitute though

Comment: Yes, it is hard to format in these comments. But my working solution has been to use what appears to be your 2nd option. So, even with that and reboot you still don't have a working trackpad? Sorry, this is so frustrating! Also, I should have noted that this was with Linux kernel 5.8.x from the "linux-generic-hwe-20.04" hardware enablement upgrade. Are you on 5.8.x (from 20.04.2) or still on 5.4.x (from 20.04.0)?

Comment: Yes, I made many tries until I wrote something that made kind of sense, haha! And yes, frustrating is exactly the word. Specially because I don't really know what I'm doing, so I just do my best and hope for the best. The Linux Kernel I'm using is 5.8.0-43-lowlatency and the Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 20.10... I really appreciate the help!