# Wi-Fi stopped working after reinstallation

Tags: wireless, 20.10, reinstalling

I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 and updated to 20.10 but now the Wi-Fi is not working. It says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found".

This is the result from lshw:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
                description: Network controller
                product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 32
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:d1200000-d13fffff
```

`dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

```
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-33-generic       5.8.0-33.36                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; dkms status`

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8111E Ethernet LOM
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38f7]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0827]
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir [1002:1636] (rev c6)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Renoir [17aa:3a44]
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.8.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed

sudo dmesg | grep ath

[    2.458101] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to alloc CE src ring 0: -12
[    2.458108] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to allocate copy engine pipe 0: -12
[    2.458111] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to allocate copy engine pipes: -12
[    2.458114] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to setup resource: -12
[    2.460062] ath10k_pci: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -12
[    2.595278] Modules linked in: snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep amd64_edac_mod(-) edac_mce_amd ath10k_pci amdgpu(+) snd_pcm kvm_amd ath10k_core snd_seq_midi nouveau(+) snd_seq_midi_event kvm ath snd_rawmidi mac80211 uvcvideo iommu_v2 crct10dif_pclmul gpu_sched snd_seq btusb videobuf2_vmalloc ghash_clmulni_intel videobuf2_memops btrtl mxm_wmi videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm ttm btintel snd_seq_device aesni_intel snd_timer videobuf2_common bluetooth drm_kms_helper crypto_simd videodev cryptd input_leds glue_helper ecdh_generic cec rapl mc serio_raw efi_pstore hid_multitouch wmi_bmof cfg80211 ecc snd rc_core k10temp snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops soundcore libarc4 syscopyarea snd_pci_acp3x sysfillrect sysimgblt ccp cm32181 industrialio mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_generic crc32_pclmul psmouse nvme ahci r8169 xhci_pci i2c_piix4 libahci xhci_pci_renesas nvme_core realtek wmi video i2c_hid hid
[   27.766675] audit: type=1107 audit(1609348791.668:66): pid=766 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=2382 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=767 peer_label="unconfined"
[   28.623047] audit: type=1107 audit(1609348792.524:67): pid=766 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=2382 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=779 peer_label="unconfined"
[   28.623694] audit: type=1107 audit(1609348792.524:68): pid=766 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=2382 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=779 peer_label="unconfined"
[   28.646185] audit: type=1107 audit(1609348792.548:69): pid=766 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=2382 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=779 peer_label="unconfined"
[   28.646951] audit: type=1107 audit(1609348792.548:70): pid=766 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=2382 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=779 peer_label="unconfined"
```

Comment: What was the goal of installing 20.04 and updating to 20.10? Why not install either of those and keep? It looks like the upgrade process didn't finish well and your kernel is not properly installed.

Comment: The problem is that I've been trying the touchpad to work and after many things tried the laptop was a bit strange with some stuff like when turning on.

Comment: I also asked about the touchpad on another question, seems like is a problem of the laptop model: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303518/trackpad-lenovo-ideapad-3-ubuntu-not-working

Comment: How can I install it properly?

Comment: Any result from terminal for `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)` and post result for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; dkms status`

Comment: dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-33-generic       5.8.0-33.36                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

Comment: The other information seems to be too long to be able to post it, I don't understand why. I'm new to all this.

Comment: Ok, I added the information

Comment: What is the result for `sudo modprobe -v ath10k_pci; dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: There I added it. Thank you!

Comment: Is it a dual boot?

Comment: Yes. Windows 10 with Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: Reboot to Windows and disable Fast Startup Feature of Windows. Then reboot to Ubuntu.

Comment: Didn't work. I can not even find in an easily way the wireless connections. Is as if was not installed.

Comment: I would file a bug report against package linux, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 0):

I updated the kernel from 5.8.0 to 5.10.4 and now it works. Thank you!