# Unable to use touchpad during Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, touchpad, lenovo, usb-installation

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad with Microsoft Windows 10 Operating System. It's a brand new system and I wanted to install Ubuntu on this machine replacing windows OS. But I'm not able to use touchpad during installation and I'm afraid it might the same post installation as well.

Keyboard is working during installation. The problem is only with touchpad. Anyone else faced the same issue?

Also I received some errors while booting Ubuntu from USB:

```
0.1698611 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol (_SB.PCBO.DGPVI,

AE NOT FOUND (20190B16/psargs-330) 0.1698731 ACPI Error: Aborting method SB.PC00.PEGO.PCRP. ON due to previo

us error CAE NOT FOUND) (20190816/psparse-531) 4.662686) integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
```

Comment: Not all touchpads are supported bu Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this same issue with new Lenovo Ideapad 3 and V15 laptops. Please try to change grub settings according to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1302468/9578